# Foreach in java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a method that:

1. have list of CustomObjects,
2. get variable param
3. and should return a list of strings with ids of objects that have param

CustomObject looks like:

```
{
    "id": "1a",
    "secondObjectList": [{
        "name": "a",
        "params": ["param1", "param2", "param3"]
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "params": ["param2"]
    }]
}
```

Method with stream that works when object have only one param:

```
public List<String> findObjectsIdsThatHaveParam(List<CustomObject> objectsList, String param) {
    return objectsList.stream()
            .filter(object -> object.getSecondObjectList.get(0).getParams().contains(param))
            .map(CustomObject::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I don't know how to iterate by params arrayList. Do you know how I can do it using stream?

Comment: Use `filter(o -> o.getParams().contains(param))`

Comment: In that case you have right. My mistake, array should have an next object with aray. I will edit it.

Comment: if you want to accept objects having at least one param containing (and not being equal to) the give string, then use `filter(o -> o.getParams().stream().anyMatch(p -> p.contains(param))`

Comment: Please add proper Java class for `ObjectClass` to avoid any type of wrong answers/comments.

Comment: Anyway, my point was that `params` is a `List<String>` and you seem to want to know if *one of* those strings is the given `param`, aka is equal to the given value, which is done by calling the `List` method `contains(String s)`. Do that by removing the `get(0)`, otherwise you're calling `String.contains(String)`, which is a substring search, and not what you want.

Comment: I edited question, now should be better but it's only example.

Comment: Now with the double-nested lists, use `filter(o -> o.getSecondObjectList().stream().anyMatch(x -> x.getParams().contains(param)))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused as to how to iterate through all of the elements until the provided criteria is met.

streams utilise internal iteration, so you can just
create a stream from the `getSecondObjectList` and utilise `anyMatch` providing your criteria.

```
.filter(object -> object.getSecondObjectList.stream()
               .anyMatch(e -> e.getParams().contains(param)))
...
...
```